# How to identify one of several Firefox installations (location) by id from `~/.mozilla/firefox/installs.ini`?

Tags: linux, firefox

I'm writing scripts and see that `~/.mozilla/firefox/installs.ini` now as I've downloaded and started another version of Firefox contains two sections with ids, same ids in `profiles.ini` - as I understand this is how Firefox knows which profile to load as default  for each install (when I changed profile name in that file, it started to load the profile I put there). But I was not able to find config/ini file in the folder from where `firefox` is started that contained that id.

How does Firefox knows which profile to load for each install if not from `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`? How to select among found (by e.g. file search for `firefox` file with executable permission) installations (folders with `firefox` executable) one corresponding to a particular id from  `~/.mozilla/firefox/installs.ini`? I was not able to find the info by web search.

Comment: @Artem, thank you for trying to help. I've explained that I have two folders with two FF versions. By editing `profiles.ini` in a section of a particular id I choose which profile it loads. So it (firefox exec) knows which id it belongs to. If you think the question is not clear, please advice how to improve.

Comment: @Artem, I understand I probably cannot locate FF from id by itself, I "merely" want to confirm it is correct one when found by other means.

Answer (score 1):

So this is only a partial answer, but the default profile for each install is the one written in both `installs.ini` and `profiles.ini`.

For instance, I've just "burnt" a new MX Linux Live USB. I start firefox, and the contents of the ini files are following:

```
demo@mx1:~/.mozilla/firefox
$ cat installs.ini 
[6AFDA46A1A8AD48]
Default=ja0llll6.default-release
Locked=1

demo@mx1:~/.mozilla/firefox
$ cat profiles.ini 
[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=83agh85a.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=ja0llll6.default-release

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

[Install6AFDA46A1A8AD48]
Default=ja0llll6.default-release
Locked=1
```

The profile that has been loaded is `ja0llll6.default-release`.
Now from firefox, in the `about:profiles` page, I change the default profile for the other one. Now the contents are:

```
demo@mx1:~/.mozilla/firefox
$ cat installs.ini 
[6AFDA46A1A8AD48]
Default=83agh85a.default
Locked=1

demo@mx1:~/.mozilla/firefox
$ cat profiles.ini 
[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=83agh85a.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=ja0llll6.default-release

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

[Install6AFDA46A1A8AD48]
Default=83agh85a.default
Locked=1
```

As you can see, the default has switched to `83agh85a.default` in both `installs.ini` and `profiles.ini`.

Notice that the `Default=1` entry only tells now (for firefox>=67) what *used to be* the default profile (see article of the link below).

What is still unclear is when there are several installation sections in the `installs.ini` that also show up in the `profiles.ini`.

For instance, here are the contents of the `ini` files of my local computer:

```
nico@xantico:~/.mozilla/firefox$ cat installs.ini 
[46F492E0ACFF84D4]
Default=s25g8abr.dev-edition-default
Locked=1

[4F96D1932A9F858E]
Default=waxl9k8u.default
Locked=1

nico@xantico:~/.mozilla/firefox$ cat profiles.ini 
[Install46F492E0ACFF84D4]
Default=s25g8abr.dev-edition-default
Locked=1

[Install4F96D1932A9F858E]
Default=waxl9k8u.default
Locked=1

[Profile1]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=v6gmyi1u.default-release

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=waxl9k8u.default
Default=1

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2
```

Without any other information, I bet there is no way to tell which profile is used. I don't know if the informations from paperclip optimizer may help to find out which is the "current" hash.

Reading this might be of interest (but it's quite not easy to understand, I could not understand how to solve this question):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/understanding-depth-profile-installation

Comment: thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this very same issue all day and after hours of trial and error and sifting thru tons of incomplete / misleading documentation and useless Google results I finally figured the answer.

The hex string in each installation name is obtained from converting the  installation path string into an array of integers and digesting it with Google's 64-bit City hash function.

Here is Google's announcement of the hash function family with a link to the whitepaper:
https://opensource.googleblog.com/2011/04/introducing-cityhash.html

And here are a few implementations in C++, Go and Rust:

https://github.com/google/cityhash

https://github.com/bradenhilton/cityhash/blob/main/cityhash.go

https://docs.rs/fasthash/latest/fasthash/city/index.html

Firefox implements its own version in nsis/Contrib/CityHash/cityhash/city.cpp.

Comment: Maybe the OP will understand how this answers the question, but I don’t.  Can you add some detail & content?

Comment: @G-Man Yes, sure, I am willing to expand on my answer if you tell me exactly what information is missing. OP asked how to select between the different mozilla installations' profiles, which are stored in the files profiles.ini and installations.in the mozilla cache folder. This is tricky because instead of installation paths or names in the files there are only hexadecimal strings with no obvious interpretation.

Comment: For one thing, how do you “convert the installation path string into an array of integers”? But the bottom line is: I don’t see how you’ve answered the question: how does Firefox know which profile to load as default for each install?

Comment: Aha. Well OP is really asking two related questions now that I notice. One first one is, as you mention how does Firefox know which profile to load for each installation, which is stored in profile.ini.
The other, which is also in the title, is how does Firefox identify which installation it is supposed to read from installation.ini, which determines which subset of profiles it will look at in profile.ini.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain the issue and the solution really. It is obviously possible to have multiple versions of Firefox installed in the same filesystem, each with their own profile(s), but they will all use the same folder (in user's home) to store cached data, profiles, extensions and so on. However the way each Firefox executable knows which "installation" data to use is by hashing its installation path and checking the configuration folders stored in the  *.ini files under that name, rather than having the string of the full installation path in human-readable format.

Comment: "Converting the installation path to an array of integers" means the path needs to be encoded as a null-terminated UTF-16 string and re-cast as an integer array before hashing it into the ID, at least according to the code, but I've tried it myself but couldn't get it to work. I have no idea why does Mozilla do any of this as opposed to storing the install paths in plain text. It is not only overly complicated but also almost completely undocumented. Perhaps there are potential security risks otherwise. Just let me know it that clears up the answer so I can edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current firefox profile folder, just type this:

```
awk -F= '{if(NF){if($1=="Path")path=$2;if($1=="Default")def=$2}else{if(def==1){print "~/.mozilla/firefox/"path;exit}}}' ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
```

I hope this helps.